# Custom Tiles in App Launcher not Showing in MySites onPrem SP2016

Tags: mysite, applauncher

I have SharePoint 2016 On-Prem and created a couple of new Tiles to appear in the App Launcher.  I can get these to show on all Web Applications accept the MySites Web Application.  Anyone experience this and what I can do to show them on MySites?

Bismarck

Comment: did you enable it on mysite web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled the feature but it took almost 24 hours to show the change.